# How to create an instance of a generic type extending another one?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create an instance of generic type L in a function. Moreover, I would like that L extends a class T and there is a function that creates a default L instance from a T instance.

I was expecting something like this, but I did not manage ... Line `const a = L::from_T(new T(42));` is obviously false.

```
class T {
    x: number;
    constructor(x: number){
        this.x = x;
    }
}

interface FromT {
    from_T(a: T): FromT;
}

function test<L extends T & FromT >(): L{
    const a = L::from_T(new T(42));
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Types can not be used *at all* during runtime. You can't call methods on generic types and can't instaniate them using `new` because they don't exist in the compiled JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an instance of a function constructing desired type from T.

```ts
class T {
    x: number;
    constructor(x: number){
        this.x = x;
    }
}

type FromTConstructor<L>=(a: T) => L

function test<L extends T>(fromT: FromTConstructor<L>): L {
    const a = fromT(new T(42));
    return a;
}

class Foo extends T {}
test(t => new Foo(t.x));
```

If subclasses of T don't need a factory fuction but take T directly in a constructor, Construct signatures can be used as an alternative:

```ts
interface TConstructable<L> {
    new(t: T): L;
}

class Bar extends T {
    constructor (a: T) {
      super(a.x);
    }
}

function test1<L extends T>(ctor: TConstructable<L>): L {
    const a = new ctor(new T(42));
    return a;
}

test1(Bar);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAq0G8BQ1XQB4C5oDsCuAtgEYCmATgNwprAD2OEALmXsI7WQBRa6GlkBKZGhHRGACwCWEAHTpoAXgxURAXyTqkjAJ4AHEtABiZWgVgBhekxZsOAHgAyAPgWcw2WAMVPoDpEgAzPBw2SXoxEiZHaBJ0RhIcABMYWCdOAJMzbGNTCytmVnYyRycBbAdEalQ6BkZoMEVoDNzOHBIAdzhOABYAJgEBFTQyEkY8Mhx6qk1QSBhDWloYuITkuER1eKZOOoUfNs6F2h25Aap-JEkceLIAsGADPNqbRjAiEBISypEDnY8y3zTfyzKDQABCYDIy3iSRS3xo+ReHGgbn+8JEEDw+i4YFOQ1Q6k0QRCjDCky2jAAjNFYjC1qlOLYyB5LM9Cm8PiUARVhAjavVGgdoEzWh0un0zlVoCMxhMphp-BTKZwIYIKEA)